# Purge old folders without find

Tags: linux, shell-script, scripting

Here I am trying to delete old folders which are older then xdays.
Path of these disk are mentioned in file_path.txt

What I need here is to search each path available in the mentioned file & delete those files which are available.

Below is what i have tried so far, but not working.

```
dir_to_check='file_path.txt'
CY=`date +"%Y"`
last_month=`date '+%B' --date '1 month ago'`
lmdate=`date '+%d' --date='32 days ago'`

cmd="$dir_to_check/$CY/$last_month/$lmdate"

cat file_path.txt | while read output
do
find $cmd -type d -ctime +30
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
echo "Directory exists and can be deleted"
echo "rm dir"
else
echo "FAIL to delete directory as its not exists"
fi
done
```

Comment: Why do you say you don't want to use `find`? Particularly as your example uses it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible error in the algorithm:

```bsh
dir_to_check='file_path.txt'
CY=`date +"%Y"`
last_month=`date '+%B' --date '1 month ago'`
lmdate=`date '+%d' --date='32 days ago'`

cmd="/$CY/$last_month/$lmdate"

cat $dir_to_check | while read output
do
        find ${output}${cmd} -type d -ctime +30 
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                echo "Directory exists and can be deleted"
                echo "rm dir"
        else
                echo "FAIL to delete directory as its not exists"
        fi  
done
```

Consider using the `-exec` option in the `find` utility instead of a return value `$?`.

Comment: `rm dir` should have the variable path of the directory which should be deleting

Comment: @AReddy, `find ${output}${cmd} -type d -ctime +30 -delete -printf 'rm dir %p\n'`